# How can I use Github API to get a list of users added to a repository

Tags: api, github

I would like to get all users and teams for a GitHub repository using the API.
I can get the teams by using this: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repository-teams

However, I did not find how to get the list of users added directly to the project.
In the following image, I have Team A & Team B, that are returned by the API endpoint previously mentioned. However the user `me` is not returned.

[image: team a/me/ team b]

Any pointers on how I could get all the information I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repository collaborators can be listed using the [*Collaborators API*](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/collaborators) as follows:

```
[GET] /repos/{owner}/{repo}/collaborators
```

By default, you will get a list of all users with access to the repository. You can filter the returned result using the `affiliation` parameter set to `direct` in order to get only the users added directly. In your case, this would be only the user `me`.

*Example using the API with the GitHub command line tool:*

```
gh api -X GET repos/{owner}/{repo}/collaborators -f affiliation='direct'
```